# Adding directories in hash AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My site uses a script to navigate through pages with AJAX. The home page url is for example this: `http://example.com/#home`, the actual home page is located in `pages/page_home.php`.

How can I add directories in the hash? This is my code.

```
<?php

if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

$page = $_POST['page'];

if(file_exists('pages/page_'.$page.'.php'))
echo file_get_contents('pages/page_'.$page.'.php');

else echo '<div class="box">404 - That page could not be found. <a href="#home">Click here</a> to return.</div>';
?>
```

My motive to do this is to make a *conditions* page so when a visitor clicks on the cookies link in `/#conditions` the URL changes to `/#conditions/cookies` which is neater.

EDIT: full code

```
var state = { 'page_id': 1, 'user_id': 5 };
var title = 'Hello World';
var url = '#conditions/cookies';

history.pushState(state, title, url);


var default_content="";

$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    options.async = true;
});

$(document).ready(function(){

    checkURL();
    $('ul li a').click(function (e){

            checkURL(this.hash);

    });

    //filling in the default content
    default_content = $('#pageContent').html();


    setInterval("checkURL()",250);

});

var lasturl="";

function checkURL(hash)
{
    if(!hash) hash=window.location.hash;

    if(hash != lasturl)
    {
        lasturl=hash;

        // FIX - if we've used the history buttons to return to the homepage,
        // fill the pageContent with the default_content

        if(hash=="")
        $('#pageContent').html(default_content);

        else
        loadPage(hash);
    }
}


function loadPage(url) {

    url=url.replace('#','');

    $.post("load_page.php", page: location.hash.substring(1)), function () {
      history.pushState(null, '', '#conditions/cookies');
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: location.hash,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0) {
                $('#pageContent').html(msg);
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Er... Something like `<a href="/#conditions/cookies">`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I know that, but the script isn't made for that. It currently only supports links like `/#conditions`, not `/#conditions/cookies`.

Comment: Then you need to change your scripts to send AJAX queries by sending the value of `location.hash` to the PHP. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To add directories to the URL, you can use `history` API. To add a new directory, or change the `#` part:

```
var state = { 'page_id': 1, 'user_id': 5 }; // This is totally irrelevant.
var title = 'Hello World';                  // Some title/
var url = '#conditions/cookies';            // The main URL.

history.pushState(state, title, url);
```

And now, in your AJAX call, send the `#hash` value by sending:

```
data: location.hash                         // This sends condition/cookies to PHP.
```

So building your AJAX will be something like this:

```
$.post("page.php", page: location.hash.substring(1)), function () {
  history.pushState(null, '', '#conditions/cookies');
});
```

Comment: Very interesting. How would this work? Just put this in the ajax file?

Comment: The `location.hash` will contain `"#conditions/cookies"` in `http://example.com/#conditions/cookies`. Try it out.

Comment: @Mia Check the updated answer with full example and tell me if it helps?

Comment: I will try it out right now. Sounds like a perfect script.

Comment: I have some trouble installing in, I will update the post with my ajax script. I'm almost 100% sure I'm installing it the wrong way, haha.

Comment: @Mia Yikes, totally wrong... Why have you put that `pushState` out of nowhere?

Comment: Should I remove all code and start over in a clean, new file? Or do I need to keep the old code in there? I really want to use the script you provided me with.

Comment: @Mia Better to start with a clean state to use the code I have provided. `:)` Others are interfering...

Comment: @Mia Are you still around?

Comment: Yes, I'm still here. I want to accept your answer but I haven't really got my solution working yet

Comment: @Mia Ask me what you wanna do? Where are you stuck up?

Comment: @Mia Grrr.. That's a funny answer, okay. See do one thing. Lemme create a minimally working JS and I don't think the PHP is bad. So, only stuff is, I will create a set of JS and HTMLS now.

Comment: @Mia Done. Do you have a way that I can send you files?